# Qual da diferença entre PDO e Mysqli_?

Tags: php, pdo, mysqli

Faz tempo que densevolvo aplicativos em PHP MySQL, e pra norlamente uso o objeto `PDO` pra conectar-se com a `base de dados` e tudo funciona perfeitamente.
Mais hoje decidi sair da minha ignorancia e gostaria de testar o famoso `mysqli_`:

- Quais sao as grandes diferenças entre esses dois metodos ?
- Em que circunstancias devem ser usados ?

Comment: Um suporta somente o MySQL enquanto o PDO suporta vários banco de dados. Se estiver usando MySQL seria preferível utilizar o MySQLi, se não utiliza o MySQL  "só restará" utilizar o PDO.

Comment: Não entendo como uma pergunta praticamente duplicada(idêntica) a uma com 40 up pode receber negativo, que tal explicar ao AP o motivo do negativo, para ele aprimorar ?

Comment: @MagicHat aqui é assim que as coisas funciona ... Muito triste !!

Comment: Não generalize, man...

Comment: @MagicHat tem um fator para isso acontecer é claro é só ver o contexto geral ... a resposta é excelente o problema não é a resposta ...

Comment: @VirgilioNovic desulpe man , não entendi...

Comment: @MagicHat eu votei a favor já faz tempo, gostei da resposta, mas, sempre tem pessoas que não gostam daquilo que postamos e isso é um dos fatores, como você mesmo disse não consigo entender. A rede é grande e isso acontece por vários fatores. Tenhamos consciência que a maioria vota certo.

Comment: @VirgilioNovic ah saquei...